# Module reads package from both

Tags: java, gradle, bouncycastle, flying-saucer

I found something similar to my problem, but it is related to maven not gradle: [java 9 unnamed module reads package [X] from both ... while debugging (with IntelliJ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445583/java-9-unnamed-module-reads-package-x-from-both-while-debugging-with-inte)

I finally decided to start using the new-ish module system in java on my existing project. I created a module-info.java that contains:

```
requires com.sothawo.mapjfx;
requires MaterialFX;
requires thymeleaf;
requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore;
requires bugsnag;
requires org.jfxtras.styles.jmetro;
requires org.slf4j;
requires javafx.swing;
requires itext;
requires flying.saucer.pdf;
```

And my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation ('io.github.palexdev:materialfx:11.13.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
}

implementation ('org.jfxtras:jmetro:11.6.15') {
    exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
}

implementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.1.0.M1'
implementation 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.22'

implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.1'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'

implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36'

implementation 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag:3.6.3'

implementation 'com.sothawo:mapjfx:3.1.0'

testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}
```

I keep getting these sort of errors each time I try to build:

```
module ChanceTracker.main reads package org.bouncycastle.tsp.cms from both bctsp.jdk14 and org.bouncycastle.pkix

error: the unnamed module reads package org.xhtmlrenderer.simple from both flying.saucer.pdf and flying.saucer.core
```

(along with a bunch of others that seems to be very closely related)

running dependencies shows this (showing only the relevent parts here):

```
+--- org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.22
|    +--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7
|    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.64
|    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.64
|    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk14:1.64
|    |         \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.64
|    +--- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:1.46
|    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.46 -> 1.64
|    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.46 -> 1.64 (*)
|    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.64
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core:9.1.22
```

I rarely experiment with gradle, but I tried different 'excludes' in my dependencies with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with

```
implementation ('org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.22') {
    exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle'
    exclude group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to exclude the module

```
implementation ("io.kubernetes:client-java:15.0.1") {
        exclude group:"com.google.code.findbugs", module: "jsr305"
}
```

since I didn't see it being used anyway