# How to exclude packages in Maven that uses the same attribute?

Tags: java, maven, soap, module-info

So, I am working with webservices using SOAP and Maven. This error - I think - is a warning instead because it let me run the application and the service just fine for now. Whenever I call any other package inside this module class it turns red. If I don't add packages the error disappears but I need jasperreports (strange, as the involved package got nothing to do with this)

I've followed this: [Module reads package from both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71316990/module-reads-package-from-both)
Using the solution "implementation and excludes" does nothing. Probably because it is Gradle but I had to try restricting the xml transform using the suggested message.

I also tried [Package 'com.example' reads package 'javafx.beans' from both 'javafx.base' and 'javafx.base'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548096/package-com-example-reads-package-javafx-beans-from-both-javafx-base-and) this.

I followed this guide as well. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional> <!-- value will be true or false only -->
</dependency>
```

Making those package use optional does not help either.

***Important note***, using a different package I want to use the *ERROR WILL CHANGE*. I removed and added some so you can withness it. Check these:

[image: err]
[image: err2]
[image: err3]

Comment: What is this `webservices-api` module? Is it this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.metro/webservices-api ? If so, remove it, because it doesn't seem to do anything except bundle some other Jakarta EE packages.

Comment: I've also checked https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.metro/webservices-extra-xmlsec, and it's just as terrible. It only bundles commons-codec and SLF4J.

Comment: Seems like it groupid org.glassfish.metro artifactid webservices-rt version 2.3

Comment: The message is still there. Package reads javax.xml.transform from both java.xml and xml.apis even with the changes.

Comment: You'll probably have to repeat this process a few times, removing another dependency (sometimes a transitive dependency...) until you get it right. Sometimes bumping versions may help, but other times you'll just have to do it the hard way...

Comment: Yes, definitely going hardcore now one by one hahaha. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In short, a Web Service dependency using some of the declared in the client as well. As mentioned, I went one by one until I found it.
Also, updating javax.xml version of the dependency was a necessary step in order to solve the problem.